# ffmpeg read from a file and apply filter_complex at once

Tags: ffmpeg

I am feeding `fls.txt` into `ffmpeg -i` and applying `concat` and a speedup.

#### `fls.txt`

```
file 'input1.mp4'
file 'input2.mp4'
file 'input3.mp4'
```

#### The command in one go looks as follows:

```
ffmpeg  -i fls.txt     \
-filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v][a];\
[v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v1];[a]atempo=2,asetpts=N/SR/TB[a1]"     \
-c:v h264_nvenc -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]"  x2.mp4
```

The output is really weird and says something like `a` stream is not found. And it also looks like as if it's trying to understand the `fls.txt` itself and not its content as the parameters.
What am I doing wrong here and how can I correct it?
Also, it's a simplified example and I cannot write per hand 3 input file paths. I need it to be read from a file. I'm on windows 10 if that matters.

EDIT:
From doing the suggested edits and expanding the `-filter_complex` I get an error below.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i fls.txt     \
-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v1];[v1]setpts=0.5*PTS[v2];[0:a]atempo=2,asetpts=N/SR/TB[a1];[a1]atempo=2,asetpts=N/SR/TB[a2]"     \
-c:v h264_nvenc -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]" x2.mp4 \
-c:v h264_nvenc -map "[v2]" -map "[a2]" x4.mp4
```

error:

```
Output with label 'v1' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.
```

Comment: Add `-f concat -safe 0` before `-i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description … matches no streams.

To enable the concat demuxer you have to use `-f concat` before `-i fls.txt`.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i fls.txt     \
-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v1];[0:a]atempo=2,asetpts=N/SR/TB[a1]"     \
-c:v h264_nvenc -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]" x2.mp4
```

Because you're attempting to use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) there is no need for the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) as well, so you can simplify the command.

You may also have to use `-safe 0` before -`i` which you can read about in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options).

#### Follow-up question: Output with label 'v1' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere

You can't reuse consumed filter output labels so this example avoids that:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i fls.txt     \
-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[2xv];[0:v]setpts=PTS/4[4xv];[0:a]atempo=2,asetpts=N/SR/TB[2xa];[0:a]atempo=4,asetpts=N/SR/TB[4xa]"     \
-c:v h264_nvenc -map "[2xv]" -map "[2xa]" x2.mp4 \
-c:v h264_nvenc -map "[4xv]" -map "[4xa]" x4.mp4
```

Comment: I tried implementing the changes and added the original idea of having multiple outputs, yet getting a weird error. ```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i fls.txt     \
-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v1];[v1]setpts=0.5*PTS[v2];[0:a]atempo=2,asetpts=N/SR/TB[a1];[a1]atempo=2,asetpts=N/SR/TB[a2]"     \
-c:v h264_nvenc -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]" x2.mp4 \
-c:v h264_nvenc -map "[v2]" -map "[a2]" x4.mp4
```
error:
```
Output with label 'v1' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.
```

Comment: I have a follow-up to the question if you had time to have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231770/invalid-dropping-st0-and-non-monotonous-dts-in-output-stream-01-errors-in-ffmp