# invalid dropping st:0 and Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1 errors in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would really be thankful if I could get help with the following.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt   
       -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=.5*PTS[v1];
       [0:a]atempo=2,asetpts=N/SR/TB[a1]"
       -c:v h264_nvenc -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]"  x2_merged_vid.mp4
```

But I get 2 errors and the resulting video is broken with the sound disappearing around the middle of the video.
One type of the errors (there are **loads** of those) is this:

```
[mp4 @ 0000019d21d66040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 28555274, current: 11264; changing to 28555275. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

The other type of errors is like so:

```
DTS 41437099, next:291253341916 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS 41437099, next:291253341916 invalid dropping st:0
```

The full log file is [here](https://gofile.io/?c=kz887a). 
I am stumbled since I enforced `asetpts=N/SR/TB`, but the DTS and PTS are still not working properly..
What else can I do to make it output a correct file? I am not constrained in resources and can re-encode the whole thing frame by frame, but I cannot find how to do it.

EDIT: It still does not work even with the approach of using `concat` filter. Same DTS/PTS errors.

```
    -filter_complex "[0:v:0][1:v:0]...[299:v:0]concat=n=300:v=1:a=0,fps=fps=30[cv1];
                         [0:a:0][1:a:0]...[299:a:0]concat=n=300:v=0:a=1,asetpts=N/SR/TB[ca1];
                   [cv1]setpts=0.25*PTS[v4];
                   [ca1]atempo=4,asetpts=N/SR/TB[a4]"
    -c:v h264_nvenc  -map "[v4]" -map "[a4]"  result.mp4
```

I have uploaded the logs outputs from the ffmpeg and ffprobe in [(filepath,json),(filepath,json),...] [here][2](https://gofile.io/?c=kNHiDi). 
I have been scratching my head why those PTS can't be synced. Via ffprobe all v:0 and a:0 streams start from 0. I checked their stream0 and stream1 durations also and they also match. I also have a feeling that not all of the video files get concatenated in the resulting video. Maybe the issue is with the `h264_nvenc`?

Comment: Do all inputs have the same parameters?

Comment: Actually, I found the cause of the problem. It's such that either resolution or SAR are somewhat different. Is there a way to make ffmpeg automatically figure out the minority of the files that need to be adjusted to do the `concat`? Or the only way is to write a `ffprobe` routine and then reencode?

Comment: I doubt the width/height/aspect difference is giving you the DTS warnings. *Is there a way to make ffmpeg automatically figure out the minority of the files that need to be adjusted to do the concat?* No, but you can look into the scale2ref filter or use ffprobe and then scale + pad/crop. Try it without `asetpts=N/SR/TB`.

Comment: Could you please give a simple example of how to use `scale2ref` (it sounds interesting)? I have opened this https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-scale2ref but cannot figure out how to make, say, all 5 videos from the mylist.txt reference the 3rd video...  From this example `[logo-in][video-in]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih/10[logo-out][video-out]` I don't follow where the `oh` and `ih` parameters are taken from. Is it that `scale2ref` takes in only 2 arguments and the 0-th is the one to be scaled and the 1st is the one to be referenced while scaling?

Comment: That's a completely different topic than the question above, so I recommend first searching for `[ffmpeg] is:answer scale2ref`, and if you don't find anything then post a new question about that topic.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I actually figured out a proper way to do that over the last week. I totally would not recommend using `-f concat` as it's a waste of time for most cases, especially, with lots of videos. Using `-filter_complex "[0:v:0][1:v:0]...concat=n=N:v=1:a=0,fps=fps=30[cv];[0:a:0][1:a:0]...concat=n=N:v=0:a=1,asetpts=N/SR/TB[ca];[cv]setpts=.25*PTS[outv];[ca]atempo=4[outa]"  -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" res.mp4` after `ffprobe` and running rescaling (and re-sar-ing) where needed works the best. Not sure why such a straight-forward operation got implemented so convoluted.

Comment: It still does not work... I cannot understand how to look for the issue since the error messages from ffmpeg are so uninformative. I know something's wrong with the PTS/DTS but I have no idea at which step of the filtergraph.

Comment: Show full log of `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -i input3`: these being the inputs listed in `mylist.txt`.

Comment: It's here. `logs_unity.txt` https://gofile.io/?c=kNHiDi

Comment: I have added into the EDIT section.

Comment: Without any line breaks the log is unreadable. I did not realize you are attempting to concatenate 300 files. Do you have a minimized command that duplicates the issue using as few inputs as possible?

Comment: Took me some time with breaking them into samples and I found the file that was causing the problems.  https://gofile.io/?c=ov9re8 `180....txt` is the `ffmpeg` log. `ffprobe ....txt` is 10 files in the sample where the 9th file (streams #8:0,#8:1, file "23 Moving Platforms\189 Challenge Moving Platform.mp4") is causing the problems. There's also mentioning that I might want to upload it to `ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/incoming/`. So the file is also in my upload. I presume you are part of the core developers and I pray you can help me understand what's wrong with the file.